# Apps Script to fill blanks with cell value above running very slowly

Tags: google-apps-script

I am currently using the code below to fill blank cells with cell value above:

```
function fillBlanks() {
  
  for (var r = 3; r <= sheetLR; r++) {
    for (var c = 2; c <= 8; c++) {
      
      if(sheet.getRange(r, c).getValue() == "") {
        
        var valInsert = sheet.getRange(r-1, c).getValue();
        sheet.getRange(r, c).setValue(valInsert);
        
      }   
    }
  }
}
```

The code works fine, however, it is very slow and keeps exceeding time limit.  Any idea on how I can speed it up?

Thanks

Fazila

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

Methods that access the sheet like `getRange()`, `getValue()` and `setValue()` have a lot of execution time, thus they are not recommended to be executed inside loops.

The best practice is to get all the values you need from a range to an array, manipulate that array in a loop, then write the array back to the range.

### Sample Code:

```
function fillBlanks() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetLR = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,2,sheetLR-1,7);
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  for (var r = 1; r < sheetLR-1; r++) {
    for (var c = 0; c < 7; c++) {
      
      if(values[r][c] == "") {
        
        values[r][c] = values[r-1][c];
        
      }   
    }
  }

  range.setValues(values);

}
```

This should do the same thing but with only two executions on the range regardless of size.

Comment: Wow that was pretty much instantaneous need to remember this for next time as I'm sure there will be one!  Thanks really appreciate it.